# Binding dependency property into another xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have created a dependency property in one of the usercontrols but need some way to bind it into another XAML(another usercontrol).Here is the C# code

DateRangeSelectorControl.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TodayDateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TodayDate",
    typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(DateRangeSelectorControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, TodayDateChanged));
```

I have another XAML(ActivityListMenuControlView.xaml) where i need to bind this property(TodayDateProperty) so that it can be exposed and it's callback called.
Here is the XAML code:

```
<DateRangeSelector:DateRangeSelectorControl x:Name="DateRangeSelector"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_TaskListDateRangeSelector"
                                            DateRangeUpdatedCmd="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionUpdatedCommand}"
                                            FontSize="{StaticResource TaskListMenuFontSize}"
                                            RangeOptions="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionOptions,
                                                                   Mode=OneTime}"
                                            SelectedDateRange="{Binding Path=SelectedRange,
                                                                        Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowFilterOptions,
                                                                 Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}" />
```

Is there any way?

UPDATE:
As per the suggestion from O.R Mapper, i have made the following change into this XAML(ActivityListMenuControlView.xaml):

> ```
>         <DateRangeSelector:DateRangeSelectorControl x:Name="DateRangeSelector"
>                                                     Grid.Column="1"
>                                                     Margin="10 0 0 0"
>                                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
>                                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
>                                                     AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_TaskListDateRangeSelector"
>                                                     DateRangeUpdatedCmd="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionUpdatedCommand}"
>                                                     FontSize="{StaticResource TaskListMenuFontSize}"
>                                                     RangeOptions="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionOptions,
>                                                                            Mode=OneTime}"
>                                                     SelectedDateRange="{Binding Path=SelectedRange,
>                                                                                 Mode=TwoWay}"
>                                                     Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowFilterOptions,
>                                                                          Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"
>                                                     TodayDateProperty="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}"
> ```

Still i get an error : Property or event expected. Upon compilation i get the following errors:

Error   2   The property 'TodayDateProperty' was not found in type 'DateRangeSelectorControl'.
Error   4   Default value type does not match type of property 'TodayDate'.

Any idea?

UPDATE:
As suggested by Sheridan, i changed the XAML to something like:

> ```
>         <DateRangeSelector:DateRangeSelectorControl x:Name="DateRangeSelector"
>                                                     Grid.Column="1"
>                                                     Margin="10 0 0 0"
>                                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
>                                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
>                                                     AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_TaskListDateRangeSelector"
>                                                     DateRangeUpdatedCmd="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionUpdatedCommand}"
>                                                     FontSize="{StaticResource TaskListMenuFontSize}"
>                                                     RangeOptions="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionOptions,
>                                                                            Mode=OneTime}"
>                                                     SelectedDateRange="{Binding Path=SelectedRange,
>                                                                                 Mode=TwoWay}"
>                                                     Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowFilterOptions,
>                                                                          Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"
>                                                     TodayDate="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}"/>
> ```

Wrapper property "TodayDate" is defined in DateRangeSelector as below:

DateRangeSelector.cs

> ```
>     public DateTime TodayDate
>     {
>         get { return (DateTime)GetValue(TodayDateProperty); }
>         set { SetValue(TodayDateProperty, value); }
>     }
> ```

And in the viewmodel(ActivityListMenuControlViewModel.cs) i created another "TodayDate"(as specified in the binding) as belowL

> ```
>     public DateTime TodayDate
>     {
>         get;
>         set;
>     }
> ```

On compilation i get the below errors:

Error   2   The property 'TodayDate' was not found in type 'DateRangeSelectorControl'.
Error   12  Default value type does not match type of property 'TodayDate'.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the property belongs to a class named `SomeClass`, of which an instance is declared in `ActivityListMenuControlView.xaml`, and is called `SomeProperty`, and assuming the Xaml snippet you are showing is a part of `ActivityListMenuControlView.xaml`, you can simply bind it like this:

```
<SomeClass SomeProperty="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}"/>
```

Comment: I tried this: TodayDateProperty="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}"      error: Property or Event expected  and where should i create property "TodayDate"

Comment: @Sandeep: You have already declared that property; you showed the respective code snippet right at the beginning of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as though your error is telling you what the problem is:

> **The property 'TodayDateProperty' was not found in type 'DateRangeSelectorControl'**. Error 4 Default value type does not match type of property 'TodayDate'.

This is because you did *not* register a `DependencyProperty` named `TodayDateProperty` in your control. So instead, try using the name of the `DependencyProperty` that you did register - `TodayDate`:

```
<DateRangeSelector:DateRangeSelectorControl x:Name="DateRangeSelector"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="10 0 0 0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_TaskListDateRangeSelector"
    DateRangeUpdatedCmd="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionUpdatedCommand}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource TaskListMenuFontSize}"
    RangeOptions="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionOptions, Mode=OneTime}"
    SelectedDateRange="{Binding Path=SelectedRange, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowFilterOptions, 
        Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"
    TodayDate="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, I think that I see what your problem is now. You are trying to data bind from your control to a view model property. What your `Binding.Path` will look like will depend on how your view model is 'connected' to your view. Assuming that an instance of your view model is set as the `DataContext` for your view, you would then be able to access the view model property like this:

```
TodayDate="{Binding DataContext.TodayDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Of course, if your control is declared in `MainWindow` instead, then you would need to use the following syntax:

```
TodayDate="{Binding DataContext.TodayDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}}"
```

Comment: Well i did something like: TodayDate="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}".   Still i get errors:  Error 2 The property 'TodayDate' was not found in type 'DateRangeSelectorControl'  AND   Error 12 Default value type does not match type of property 'TodayDate'.